# How to copy paste a file between windows and centOS

Tags: windows-7, centos

I have a file that contains the public key and I want to put that file from windows OS to centOS OS server through putty, then kindly suggest what should I use to copy file from windows OS and paste it to CentOS Server through putty.

Waiting for your suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the centOs server over ssh, try using pscp http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

```
pscp c:\Users\elif\.ssh\id_dsa.pub elif@centosserver.com:/tmp/.
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use `ftp`/`sftp` protocol to upload/download files to/from your PC to your other (remote) machine.

For convenient, I'm using [FilaZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) which has a nice GUI to do such actions and more